# Show few lines of files* in a directory in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am trying to list the first 5 lines of all the files in a directory (creating a command in Unix). I am trying to solve this by using the head command like which looks something like this:

```
head -n 5 directory/*
```

This works files but gives an error for directories (obviously).

So, my question is how can I only apply the head command on files?

My bash script looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# description: show first/last lines of all the files in a provided directory

if [ $# -ne 3 ]
then
        echo "Error: Please provide 3 parameters."
        echo "Usage Example: lshead -head 5 [DIR]"
        exit
else
        operation=$1
        lines=$2
        directory=$3

        if [ "$operation" == "-head" ]
        then
                head -n $lines  $directory/*
        elif [ "$operation" == "-tail" ]
        then
                tail -n $lines $directory/*
        fi
fi
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated and many thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the test command to test the type of the file (regular file, directory ...)

`if test -f filename`and only perform the operation when the result of the `if` is `true`

```
    #!/bin/bash
# description: show first/last lines of all the files in a provided directory

if [ $# -ne 3 ]
then
        echo "Error: Please provide 3 parameters."
        echo "Usage Example: lshead -head 5 [DIR]"
        exit
else
        operation=$1
        lines=$2
        directory=$3

        if [ "$operation" == "-head" ]
        then
                for f in $(ls $directory)
                do

                if test -f "$directory/$f"
                then
                   echo "head $directory/$f:"
                   head -n $lines  $directory/$f
                fi
        done
        elif [ "$operation" == "-tail" ]
        then
        for f in $(ls $directory)
                do

                if test -f "$directory/$f"
                then
                   echo "tail $directory/$f:"
                   tail -n $lines  $directory/$f
                fi
                done
        fi
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

this should work

```
#!/bin/bash
...
for f in "$directory"/{*,.??*}
do
    if [ -f "$f" ]
    then
      case "$operation" in head|tail)
          echo "$directory/$f:"
          $operation -n "$lines" "$f"
      esac
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `find` command for that. You filter on a single level the file and execute for each the `head` command:

```
$ find directory/ -maxdepth 1 -type f  -exec head -5 {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. But, could you please help me add the file name and then output the lines of the files? It doesn't have to be one command. It can be a part of a script too.